# Mongo GridFS save function not performing commit on database

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, gridfs

I am working with the MongoDB GridFS for saving a file more than 16MB of file.
The java program is working fine and there is not error or exception. But the problem is that the changes are not reflecting on the Mongo console.

Here is the java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("images");
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("image");

        String newFileName = "KVImage";

        File imageFile = new File("/Users/bng/Documents/largeFile.json");

        // create a "photo" namespace
        GridFS gfsPhoto = new GridFS(db, "photo");

        // get image file from local drive
        GridFSInputFile gfsFile = gfsPhoto.createFile(imageFile);

        // set a new filename for identify purpose
        gfsFile.setFilename(newFileName);

        // save the image file into mongoDB
        gfsFile.save();

        // print the result
        DBCursor cursor = gfsPhoto.getFileList();
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

And here are the system out logs:

> { "filename" : "KVImage" , "aliases" :  null  , "chunkSize" : 261120 , "uploadDate" : { "$date" : "2017-05-01T12:34:13.858Z"} , "length" : 23761888 , "_id" : { "$oid" : "59072b4577c8a244282bbf7c"} , "contentType" :  null  , "md5" : "c2848f1f351f17405eed287e9452705e"}
>   Done

Which shows that the file is loaded fine.

But the problem is that when i query the collection "image" from the MongoDB console, i got no results.

Here is the screenshot for the MongoDB console:

[image]

Any suggestion, what could be the problem?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any code which actually determines which collection it is saved to. After the variable `collection` is defined and assigned, it is never used again.

Comment: @VinceBowdren pls look into the code carefully. db.getCollection method is showing that i am using image collection.

Comment: I don't think you've understood me.You define and set the variable at line 6 (`DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("image");`) but that variable is not used in the subsequent code at all, so the GridFS code is never told to use the collection "image".

Comment: @VinceBowdren Got your point now...